# Control won't span 2 rows in FireMonkey GridPanelLayout

Tags: firemonkey, c++builder-10.2-tokyo

I'm working in Rad Studio C++ (Tokyo 10.2.3).  I have a FM form with a TGridPanelLayout control on it with 2 rows & 2 cols.  I have two listboxes and a memo field that I want arranged like this:

[image]

Under the GridPanelLayout's ControlCollection I have col 0 set with RowSpan 2.
It works perfectly in Windows and ListBox1 fills up entire left half of the Grid.  In IOS on iPhone ListBox1 only fills up top left cell.

[image]

What is the trick to making this function correctly on IOS like it does in Win32?  I tested it on Android and it works correctly so this is just an IOS related bug.

I saw this related post ([Why won't controls span multiple columns or rows in an Android FireMonkey app?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48758081/why-wont-controls-span-multiple-columns-or-rows-in-an-android-firemonkey-app) about similar issue on Android) but I can't figure out how to solve my case.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, it looks like the bugs referenced above are still in play.  To solve this I put a 2 column 1 row GridPanelLayout control down.  In the left column I put my ListBox1 and set it to align to Client.  In the right column I put another GridPanelLayout control and set it to have 1 column and 2 rows.  In it's top row I put ListBox2 and in bottom row Memo1 - setting both to align to Client.

The only confusion in this approach was that Rad Studio as insisting on the second GridPanelLayout go into the leftmost column.  I finally figured out to click on that columns control item and then click the "Control" pulldown and set it to ListBox1.  Do the same for the other one so it's Control will be the second GridPanelLayout.

[image]